# Происхождение слова "ахинея"

Tags: этимология

Ахинея — чушь, ерунда. А откуда взялось это слово? Оно русское?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ахине́я "напыщенная, сумбурная речь, бессмыслица", укр. ахине́я – то же. Семинарское слово, вероятнее всего, из греч. ἀθηναῖος "афинский"; ср. ст.-слав. аθинѣи "ἀθηναῖος" (Супр.), сербск.-цслав. афиниискъ, откуда: ахинейская премудрость.
dic.academic.ru › Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс

То есть "ахинея" - поначалу столичная(афинская) заумная непонятная для нормальных людей речь.

Answer (score 1):

[Происхождение слова ахинея](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/)

Вообще, это делается достаточно просто: заходите на сайт http://slovari.yandex.ru/ , набираете искомое слово в поле ввода; нажимаете кнопку "Найти".

Вот если там не найдёте (или противоречивые данные будут), тогда милости просим сюда, задавать вопросы.

Comment: Вообще-то, этот ресурс создавался для того, что именно тут давали ответы на вопросы, а не отсылали куда-то еще.  
Администратор

Comment: Неужели ж для того, чтобы показать, что спрашивающий не умеет пользоваться словарём? Или для того, чтобы кто-то в очередной раз скопипастил легко находимую информацию для интересующегося? И не "куда-то ещё", а в словари, где есть готовые ответы на все подобные вопросы. Я думаю, всё-таки подобные вопросы надо разрешать задавать только вместе с готовым ответом. 

Пользователь.



Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, вы хотите в комментариях к моему ответу обсудить назначение Хэшкода?

Comment: Вообще-то, на любом форуме к слову администратора как минимум прислушиваются, а не начинают спорить.

Comment: Со всем уважением к должности - чтобы к вам прислушивались нужна, как минимум, ссылка на авторитетный источник. Например, на правила форума, в которых запрещено давать советы новичкам (или запрещено высказывать мнение о качестве вопроса).

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, тут  ивр. корень *хин*, как в *прохиндей*, *геена*.

Comment: Вообще-то, читал ли @жихарка  реаьный ответ, или в какой-нибудь этимологический словарь заглянул? Тогда - ссылочку пожалуйста.

Comment: @жихарка . Мысль правильная , но здесь не ХИН  . Здесь по другому . Смотрите мой ответ .

Comment: @Варяг-91 . "Ссылочку" смотрите в моём ответе .

Comment: @жихарка ГЕЕННА - церковно-славянское слово, обязанное происхождению греческому, тогдашнему койне средиземноморья. Но происходит, вполне возможно, от еврейского. Слово «гее́нна» является греческой формой еврейского выражения ге хинно́м и означает «долина Еннома» . Там и была свалка, всегда горевшая и зловонная.

Answer (score 0):

У Виноградова есть весьма объемное для своего жанра исследование.
http://wordhist.narod.ru/ahineja.html
Ограничиваюсь ссылкой, т.к. размер статьи и обилие версий не позволяют ни процитировать все, ни даже перечислить тут всё.

Сам Виноградов приходит к мысли, что слово - из простонародья, от диалектного "охинеть" с коревым морфом "хинь" - хула, брань.

Answer (score -1):

Ивритная версия для <<**АХИНЕЯ**>>, как считает **@жихарка** , вполне состоятельна . Но здесь не корень ХИН , как она предполагает , - в иврите другой характер словообразования , нежели в русском языке . Здесь ивритное **עַכן** / справа-налево буквы *аин-каф-нун софит* ; либо  **עַכנָא** (*аин -каф - нун + алеф*) ; либо  **עכנאי** (*аин - каф - нун + алеф + йуд*) , - все три  имеют значение <<**ЗМЕЯ** (**архаическое**)>> ,  также <<РОГАТАЯ ГАДЮКА>> . Скриншот из ИРИС-словаря д-ра Баруха Подольского смотрите ниже . Судя по всему , здесь указание на библейского **змея-искусителя** в райском саду , который своими лживыми речами привёл к грехопадению Адама и Еву . То есть , <<**АХИНЕЯ**>> это **лживые , льстивые , коварные речи** . Позднее , когда первоисходник забылся , трансформировалось в <<**ЧУШЬ**>>  ,  <<**ЕРУНДА**>>  . =========================================================================== [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Черезчур замысловато. И как же этот ЭХЕН мог привести к образованию у русских(малорусских) грамотеев вполне конкретной АХИНЕИ?

Comment: @Варяг-91 . Иврит тем и специфичен , что одна и та же запись может читаться по-разному , причём самими же евреями . Кроме того , я указал три варианта для <<ЗМЕЯ>> :  помимо  עַכן эхен  ещё  и  עַכנָאי ахнай , и   עַכנָא   ахна . На скриншоте всё это наглядно видно . Чего тут не понятного ?!

Answer (score -2):

Первоначально ахинея -- пропаганда в Спарте против Афин, за что полагалась смертная казнь.

Comment: Что-то неизвестна науке такая версия...

Comment: @Историк . А можете дать примеры , чтобы Ф переходило в Х ?

Comment: @следопыт Авторитетов уважаете? Фасмера, например? http://vasmer.info/%D0%B0%D0%B0/%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F/                                                                                 Особо надо отметить, что это слово - жаргонное, бурсацкое(укр), семинаристское. В других языках не замеченное. И вовсе в нем не Ф, а θ, "фита", соответствующая нынешнему( например,  в английском) звуку, обозначаемому буквосочетанием "th"

Comment: Добавлю,интересно.В литературном языке, в его вульгарных говорах преобладает тенденция к замене х через ф (куфня, панафида; ср. филин, финифть, кафельная печь), хотя есть примеры и обратной замены — Дорохов, Астахова, Хавронья, кахель(укр) и т. п. Очевидно, это отслоения разных диалектических влияний. Можно полагать, что слово афинея возникло где-то в среде провинциального малороссийского духовенства и, потеряв связь с книжной традицией и со словами афины, афинейский и т. п., приобрело народно-диалектический облик — ахинеи. Конечно, сомнения остаются, ведь есть древний славянский корень -хин-.

Comment: @Варяг-91 . Я тоже знаю один пример . Каноническое имя <<Малахий>> имеет также форму <<Малафей>> , распространенную у старообрядцев . Ивритный первоисходник  <<МАЛИ(Ь)Т>>  /=Малюта / оканчивается на  ת  тав (не путат с ט тет , тоже Т) , а тав фонетически звучит приблизительно , как Тх . ...

Comment: ....@Варяг-91 . У таких ветхозаветных имен , как  Фара , Ионафан , Есфирь , Иудифь и др  . в ивритном оригинале везде тав , которая очень часто в перекладе меняется на Ф . Часто , но не всегда : например , Фатьян - Татьяна . В случве с Малахий - Малафей , у Мала-ф-ея тав-Тх перешло в Ф , а у Мала(Т)-х-ия было оставлено тав-Тх , но Х подавило Т .